# django rest framework foreign key serializer issue

Tags: python, json, serialization

i am new to DJango Python webservices and i am facing small issue with the serializers.here is my code.

```
**views.py**
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def sqlservice(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        posts = tbl_dcs.objects.all()
        for each in posts:
            manid = each.managerid_id
            manname = Managerid.objects.get(id = manid)
            nameser = managerSerializer(manname,many=False) 
            print nameser.data
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response({"resource":serializer.data}) 

**models.py**
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
class Managerid(models.Model):
    managername     =   models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.managername
class tbl_dcs(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address     = models.TextField()
    managerid   = models.ForeignKey(Managerid,related_name='items')
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

**serilizer.py**
from rest_framework import serializers
from mysqlservice.models import tbl_dcs
from mysqlservice.models import Managerid
class managerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Managerid
        fields = ('id', 'managername')  
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = tbl_dcs
        fields = ('id', 'name','location','address','managerid','phonenumber')
```

if i run the above code the result is...

```
{
  "resource": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ramesh",
      "location": "hyd",
      "address": "kphb,hyd",
      "managerid": 10,
      "phonenumber": 345345
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "kpti",
      "location": "kphb",
      "address": "kphb,6th phase,hyd",
      "managerid": 10,
      "phonenumber": 45456
    }
 ]
}
```

my resulting json i am unable to get the managername.How to get the managername based on managerid from the different table?.Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere.
my final json should be like below...

```
{
  "resource": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ramesh",
      "location": "hyd",
      "address": "kphb,hyd",
      "managerid": 10,
      "phonenumber": 345345,
      "managername":"xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "kpti",
      "location": "kphb",
      "address": "kphb,6th phase,hyd",
      "managerid": 10,
      "phonenumber": 45456,
      "managername":"yyyyy"
    }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `serializers.SerializerMethodField` to get manager name like below..

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    managername = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_manager_name')

    class Meta:
        model = tbl_dcs
        fields = ('id', 'name','location','address','managerid','phonenumber','managername')

    def get_manager_name(self, obj):
        return obj.managerid.managername
```

Comment: thanks for your help Trying2Learn.Please can you check once again.its not adding the managername.please check the also views.py

Comment: yes.included.But we are not changing anythng in the views.py.i think we need to change in the views.py also.

Comment: sorry. in this case you have to add the method in PostSerializer. Plz see the updates in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113621/discussion-between-trying2learn-and-user1335606).